# how to select few json values in drop down in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am getting a data from json file and the values using in dropdown but i dont want to use all values,I want to select only three values in my dropdown.

Comment: which value do you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the list at the time of feeding it to the dropdown.

```
<select ng-model="toType" class="form-control" required ng-change="ConvertCurrency()" 
ng-options="k for (k, v) in (rates | 'yourfilter') track by v"></select>
```

**[UPDATE]**

I tried to access the API, and found out that `res.data.rates` is an object and not an array.

So if you only have to show these 3 values, the easy approach would be to create a new array in controller:

```
var ratesToDisplay = []; 
ratesToDisplay.push({rate:'USD', value: res.data.rates.USD});
ratesToDisplay.push({rate:'EUR', value: res.data.rates.EUR});
ratesToDisplay.push({rate:'CAD', value: res.data.rates.CAD});
```

and feed this new filtered array to your dropdown.

```
  <select ng-model="selectedRate" ng-options="rate.value as rate.rate for rate in ratesToDisplay">
    <option value="" disabled>Please Select</option>
  </select>
```

I hope this helps.

**For 2nd part of your problem**

You can implement the `ng-change()` method and call the API from that method. Ex:

```
    function onDDChange(){
     $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?' + $scope.fromType.label)
.then(function(res) { \\logic for success call back 
    \\ call convert currency method from here.
    });
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <select ng-model="fromType" class="form-control" required 
ng-change="onDDChange()" ng-options="f as f.label for f in rates">
```

Comment: How do i select this three values in dropdown USD, EUR and CAD.

Comment: create a filter and apply hard codded checks to filter out the list. something like this : `app.filter('rateFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (input == 'USD' || input == 'EUR' || input == 'CAD')
      return input;
  };
});`

Comment: @VishalJoshi Check my updated answer for 2nd part of your problem. I hope that would help. 
Also, if you feel my solution was helpful to you, then please mark it as an answer and give an up-vote to the answer / comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code and it is working for me

```
angular.module('CurrencyConv', [' ']).controller('ConvertCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.rates = [];

$scope.toType = {};
$scope.fromType = {};

$http.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base').then(function(res) {


    $scope.fromValue = 1;
    $scope.ConvertCurrency();

    var i = 0;

    angular.forEach(res.data.rates, function(value, key) {

        if (key == "USD" || key == "EUR" || key == "CAD") {
            $scope.rates.push({ value: value, label: key });
            // $scope.toType = $scope.rates.CAD;
            // $scope.fromType = $scope.rates.USD;
        }
        i++;

    });

});
                        <select ng-model="fromType" class="form-control" required ng-change="ConvertCurrency()" ng-options="f as f.label for f in rates">
```